# finding derivative of fractions

Tags: derivatives

I am currently learning calculus and I am doing some excercises from a book, this one question really stumped me.

$$\frac{1}{2-x}$$

I tried to figure out how I could seperate the fraction so just the x is on the denominator and then mabye I can combine it again at the end, but I couldn't figure that out either.
I then checked the answer to see if that could help me figure out how I was supposed to solve it but it made me more confussed, that answer given in the book is...
$$\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$$
I understand that the derivative of the the following $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\frac{1}{x^2}$ but I dont get how the exponent gets applied to the 2 in the first example instead of just being $\frac{1}{2-x^2}$

I know how to get the derivative of a fraction if its multiplying in the denomenator but because it's subtracting I am completely stumped.
any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the chain rule is?

Comment: no, never heard of it. Ill go look into it now. thanks!

Comment: Basically, since $\frac{d}{du}( \frac{1}{u}) = -\frac{1}{u^2}$, $\frac{d}{dx}( \frac{1}{(2-x)}) = -\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$. However, by the chain rule, you have to take the derivative of the 'inside' function - $2-x$ and multiply it by the other 'outside' functions. Therefore, $-\frac{1}{(2-x)^2} * -1 = \frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$.

Comment: `the derivative of the following` $\frac{1}{x}$ `is` $\frac{1}{x^2}\,$. No, the derivative of $1/x$ is $-1/x^2$.

Comment: @dxiv I think you misread me - I did write it correctly.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for pointing that out :D

Comment: @TobyMak thanks for you help :D

Comment: @TobyMak Sorry, it looks like we crossed comments. Mine was not addressed to your (correct) derivation, but to the mistake in the posted question.